# How do you save preserve the value of an input after submission when entered into a table and sent to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, post, input

I have an assignment for a course I'm taking where we have to build a web-based game using exclusively php and css. I have chosen to make a simple version of sudoku in which the user enters their value into input fields that are stored in an array. What I want to be able to do is to have the input field maintain their entry even after pressing the submit button that would ultimately check their answers. I found some people saying you can use php to POST the input field name to the input field value, so after submission it still contains the most recently entered value, but that doesn't seem to work when sending the value to an array like I'm doing.

My code so far (also I'm very new to PHP so I might have to ask for clarification on an explanation if I don't understand it) and thanks in advance to everyone who is able to render any assistance:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST["inputs"]);
//test to see if values are being stored in the array
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Sudoku</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <?php
    function drawTable($rows, $cols){
        echo "<form method='post' target=''>";
        echo "<table>";
        for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
            echo "<tr>";
                for($j=0;$j<$cols;$j++){
                    echo '<td><input type="number" id="$i,$j" name="inputs[]" value="" inputs min="1" max="9"></td>';

            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    drawTable(9,9);
    ?>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the look of this: `id="$i,$j"`  I'd probably use an underscore, BUT more importantly, Do you need the id attribute?  Is it better to have a class attribute with two values for css reasons?

As for your `name` attribute, you can declare a multi-dimensional array like this:

`inputs[$i][$j]`

This should fix you up.

Keep in mind, you'll need to use `if(isset($_POST['inputs'][$i][$j]))...` 81 times to present the submitted values in the grid's input fields again and avoid any warnings/notices.

p.s. I'd also remove that `inputs` bit between `value` and `min`.  ...and close your form with `</form>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I think I didn't do what you said properly because this line: echo '<td><input type="number" id="$i_$j" name="inputs[$i][$j]" value="if(isset($_POST['inputs'][$i][$j]))" min="1" max="9"></td>'; causes my .php page to not load. Could you perhaps point me to where I did something wrong? Or was it that I need to have the if(isset... after I echo the input field in the j loop?

Comment: @JLH Truth be told, you have a few things to clean up.  I'll let you work with your code a bit longer and see if you can self-solve.  I'm going to bed now.  I'll check my messages in the morning.  Keep at it and good luck.   p.s. ...this is php not html, break out of echo to render the php: `if(isset($_POST['inputs'][$i][$j])){echo $_POST['inputs'][$i][$j];}`